# How often should I identify User for analytics?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

The analytics plugin allows me to identify users (`Amplify.Analytics.identifyUser(...)`). How often should I call this?

It is apparent I should call it whenever a user signs up and signs in, or signs out. But should I run it evevy time the user opens the app? Not sure what frequency is best.